# File System Architecture Software

Tags: bash, architecture, file-organization

Is there any command line utility to find ALL directories and files associated with a particular program (including pre-installed programs such as bash commands)? I want to compartmentalize all of my programs so that they're more like mobile applications, and list the contained files in chronological order starting from the invocation of the program until the last line of the last page of code.

Comment: Bash commands are built-in. I’m not sure what your ultimate goal is, but it doesn’t sound like a good idea. Please elaborate.

Comment: All I was trying to do is install Cordova and a few other apps to start developing on this computer, but with all the hidden folders and duplicate directories I feel like the computer isn't even mines. So I figured I would try and group the directories by all potential jumps within files e.g. yesterday I found out that bash apparently invokes a .profile file, but then where does it go? Or of course if you can't deduce where it'll go forsure, then log all of the paths within that file, and all of the paths within those and so on, all in order.

Comment: Yeah so it’s really just fear of the unknown. Instead of trying to isolate programs (which won’t work anyway or is super complex and error-prone), try to learn what programs do.

Comment: The command "dpkg -L <package-name>" will list all files installed by the package. The command "apt-cache depends <package-name>" will list all dependent packages of the package. Combine those commands suitably to find all files "associated" with the package. There will rarely be any possibility of "compartmentalizing".